# how to use the updatepanl and postback trigger and progress templete in asp.net ajax

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

hi i am using update panel in my project, one page i have file upload control is there, so save the page file upload is not working that time i used post back trigger control (id is button id) now my problem is progress bar is not working , please give me any suggestion. my code is

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="IBtnSave" />
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlAgent" />
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSelectCity" />
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBtnAgent" />
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ImgBtnCancel" />
         </Triggers>
```

progress bar code is

```
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="up1"
        DynamicLayout="true">
        <ProgressTemplate>
               <div id="Progressbar" class="Progressbar" align="center" valign="middle" runat="server">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="75" Height="95" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/animation_processing.gif" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

how to solve that problem, please give me any suggestion

Thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i can find out the answer it is working 
just write the java script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var updateProgress = null;

    function postbackButtonClick() {
        updateProgress = $find("<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>");
        window.setTimeout("updateProgress.set_visible(true)", updateProgress.get_displayAfter());
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

after that

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="IBtnSave" />
        </Triggers>
```

button onclick event just call that function like this

```
<asp:Button ID="IBtnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="art-button" 
                                            ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="IBtnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return postbackButtonClick();"/>
```

Comment: Hi, This is working fine, but after complete of postback how to set updateProgress.set_visible(false)...